# How to get a call to the controller when the selectbox is changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When the selectbox, with countries are changed, I want to put the name of the capital of the country in the Where field. How can I setup this to get a call back to the controller when the country is changed?

```
<div class="well">
    <form method="post" asp-action="Jobs" asp-antiforgery="true">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@Localizer["Country"]</span>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="CountryCode" asp-items="ViewBag.Countries" value="@Model.CountryCode">
                    <option disabled selected value="">@Localizer["ChooseCountry"]</option>
                </select>
           </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@Localizer["Where"]</span>
                <input asp-for="Where" class="form-control" placeholder=@Localizer["EnterCityToSearch"] value="@Model.Where"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@Localizer["What"]</span>
                <input asp-for="What" class="form-control" placeholder="@Localizer["EnterTypeOfJob"]" value=@Model.What>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                @Localizer["Search"]
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    @*<a  class="text" role="button" asp-action="ChangeSearchMetode" asp-antiforgery="true">Link Button</a>*@
 </div>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using Jquery as well. You can achieve this as:

```
$("#CountryCode").on('change', function(){

      $.ajax({
            url: 'controller action url here'
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: $("#CountryCode").val()}),
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                //now u have data. set it where and as u want
            },
            error: function() {
                //your exceptional handler
            }
       });
});
```

I'm assuming that your controller action is expecting a paramater with the name Id. The above ajax function will hit your controller action method. In controller, you should return your data in json and use it in success function of your ajax call

Comment: You're not going to be able to select via `select[asp-for="CountryCode"]`. That's tag helper code, part of ASP.NET Core. The rendered HTML should result in the select having both id and name of `CountryCode`, so you can select by either of those in the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I implemented the function (as a test) with the following changes: url: '@Url.Action("ChangeCountry", "JobSearch")', and an allert when sucess and error. - but it did not work. I never got a call back to the controller.I also never got the allert signal.

Comment: Is your controller defined in some area? You should specify the area as well..secondly ur parameters name in controller action should be same as you are passing in ajax call

Comment: @BEO - Please accept this answer if it helped you :)